# How to access only single json object from array?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json

I am getting this json object array in my $http.get response. I want any one of the two json objects to display.

// HTML code:

```
<pre ng-repeat="opportunity in opportunities track by $index">
    <span>{{opportunity | json}}</span>
</pre>
```

JSON Objects in an array:

```
    [
      {
        "type": "job",
        "userId": "5791a4cd0a53c59c52fc3230",
        "positionName": "aaaaaaaa",
        "budget": "3",
        "jobLocation": [
          "Bangalore",
          "Pune"
        ],
        "minExp": "0 year",
        "maxExp": "2 years",
        "gradMarks": null,
        "hscOrDiploma": null,
        "ssc": null,
        "jobDescription": "qq",
        "selectionProcess": "cv",
        "lastDate": "2016-07-30T18:30:00.000Z",
        "noOfPositions": "9"
      },
```

//second json object in same array

```
      {
        "type": "job",
        "userId": "5791a4cd0a53c59c52fc3230",
        "positionName": "zz",
        "budget": "3",
        "jobLocation": [
          "Bangalore",
          "Chennai",
          "Pune",
          "Hyderabad",
          "Mumbai",
          "Gurgaon"
        ],
        "minExp": "2 years",
        "maxExp": "5 years",
        "gradMarks": null,
        "hscOrDiploma": null,
        "ssc": null,
        "jobDescription": "ss",
        "selectionProcess": "aa",
        "lastDate": "2016-07-30T18:30:00.000Z",
        "noOfPositions": "5"
      }
]
```

Above is what I am doing. Please help me.

Comment: Why do you meant by any one of the two? Do you have any criteria?

Comment: please follow StackOverflow style guide. I just formatted your question and you took a second to flush it again.http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Please go through the formatting guide mentioned in the above link and modify your question accordingly. I've rolled back my last edit.

Answer (score 3):

To access a single and specific object from array i.e opportunities in here. You can do something like this :

```
$scope.theSpecificObject = $scope.opportunities[0];
```

This will get you the first json object from the array.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I have jquery table in which I am showing all opportunities and I want to display same opportunity object on its click

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by **I want any one of the two json objects to display.**. Consider you want to use 1st object:

```
<pre>
    <span>{{opportunities[0] | json}}</span>
</pre>
```

For the 2nd object:

```
<pre>
    <span>{{opportunities[1] | json}}</span>
</pre>
```

Comment: I have jquery table in which I am showing all opportunities and I want to display same opportunity object on its click

Comment: Shashank, I don't want to write hard code. I want to display associated json object on opportunity click.

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirement?

Comment: in jquery table I am showing like:

Sr.No    opportunity name     budget     Actions
 1           Java Developer       4 Lakh     View
 2           Python Developer    3 Lakh     View

So, what I want is, to show specific json object associated with each opportunity on View(link) click.

Comment: anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="getObject">
  <pre ng-repeat="opportunity in opportunities track by $index">

                                        <span ng-if="$index==getObject">{{opportunity | json}}</span>

                                        </pre>
</div>
```

Codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKYPGN